# How to determine the k value of an LL(k) grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

Suppose I'm given the grammar

```
Z-> X

X-> Y
 -> b Y a

Y-> c
 -> c a
```

The grammar is LL(K) What is the K value?

All I know is its not LL(1) since there is a predict set conflict on Y and LL(1) grammar predict set must be disjoint.

Comment: The answer is, as usual, 42. However, the grammar is also LL(j) for certain values of j less than 42.

Comment: 42 on my exam usually leads to a 0.

Comment: and yet here we are.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so luckily this question was not on my exam.

As I mentioned, the predict set conflict means its not LL(1) next you just have to observe the minimum number of look ahead need to determine a production value.

In this case two.